# Getting "Module not found" when building 3rd party framework that depends on a CocoaPods module

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Here is my situation:

- I am using CocoaPods but I **can't use the "use_frameworks!"** directive as it is not compatible with ReactNative
- I need to include another team's SDK, distributed as a .framework
- This .framework depends on `PureLayout`, which is available through Pods

Hence:

- I installed `PureLayout` through Pods.
- I manually linked the other team's SDK dragging it into Embedded Binaries, as per their instructions

Build fails with error `Module 'PureLayout' not found`. It seems that the other team's framework isn't able to find the `PureLayout` module included through Pods.

How can I fix? Remember I can't `use_frameworks!` in Podfile. Thanks.